# how to modify parameters like (style , class ..) in cakephp input?

Tags: html, css, cakephp, form-helpers

in cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email'));
```

will render

```
<div class="input email">
<label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="data[User][email]" value="" id="UserEmail" />
```

how to make this like that

```
    <input type="email" name="data[User][email]" value="" id="UserEmail" class="input_class" style="some:style;" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a "class" and/or "style" argument to your options array.

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email', 'class' => 'input_class', 'style' => 'some:style' ));
```

See the [the FormHelper documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options) for a list of all options.

Comment: `some:style` is what was used in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

if you need only input without lable you can also try in this way

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email','div'=>false, 'class' => 'input_class', 'style' => 'some:style' ));
```